# "chmod -R ug+rwx" not working in Dockerfile

Tags: permissions, docker

I am dockerizing php laravel application so my dockerfile looks like below, I am getting operation not permitted error after chmod command. Does anyone face this issue

```
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html
USER www-data

RUN chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html/storage/*
RUN chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html/bootstrap/*
RUN chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html/public/*


RUN chmod -R ug+rwx /var/www/html/storage/*
RUN chmod -R ug+rwx /var/www/html/bootstrap/*
RUN chmod -R ug+rwx /var/www/html/public/*
```

Comment: I just tested it and it does work. Maybe you are confused because you want the containing folder changed as well? The `*` glob doesn't contain the containing folder so it will only match all files and folders underneath `storage`, `bootstrap` and `public`. If you want them to be included just remove the `*` at the end.

Comment: When i run first time it works. But the main problem is if you run docker file again it ends up with operation not permitted. Can you please run dockerfile again.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Works the same even multiple times

Comment: Thanks man for you help. It's working now after rebuild